# Ignore OSX hidden "._" files from git repo

Tags: git, github

I `git add .` everything to my repo, excluding files and directories (its a Rails 4+ one). I see a bunch of hidden files starting with a dot (some including an underscore) and I need to ignore them so they won't get pushed every time. I am working from an OSX Yosemite macbook. How do I do that? Is it simple regEx `^._*` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.*` to make him ignore all hidden files (starting with a dot).

So you can add to your `[PROJECT]/.gitignore` file:

```
.*
!/.gitignore
```

*The second line is here to keep the `.gitignore` file.*

Comment: No, but you can `git reset .myfile` (assuming you didn't pushed)

Comment: There are lots of "." files among all directories, so it's impossible to reset all of them by hand.

Comment: Can you tidy up your answer to mention that the commands you gave should be placed into .gitignore file, and specifically which one?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Edit: Mentionned that it has to be done in the .gitignore.
*Do anybody really use multiple .gitignore files? They probably miss SVN...*

Answer (score 0):

I think adding

```
._*
```

In .gitignore file will do the trick.